# Scala: How to include a JS script to Mustache template in Finatra?

Tags: javascript, scala, mustache, finatra

I'm trying to include a JS script within my mustache template file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script id="{{app.js}}" type="text/mustache"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    Users:
    <ul>
        {{#users}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/users}}
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is located in `src/main/resources/templates/users.mustache`. Also I have a JS script in `src/main/resources/public/app.js`.

A few words about backend. I'm using `Finatra` framework with support of Mustache out of the box:

```
  get("/users") {
    req: Request => {
      response.ok.view("/users.mustache", Users)
    }
  }
```

So here is my question. How can I add a JS script to my Mustache template?

**UPD**

I also tried to use

```
<script src='{{path}}/public/app.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

But my app still doesn't see the script.

**UPD2** (thx to @nuc)

I didn't find any good solution but only this one:

```
get("/public/:*") {
  req: Request => {
    req.params.get("*") match {
      case Some(fn) =>
        val file = new File("/Users/fink/projects/finatra-demo/src/main/resources/public/" + fn)
        response.ok.file(file)
      case None => {
        response.notFound("Oh no!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I placed all assets to

```
src/main/resources/public/*
```

And in my view it should be `<script src='/public/js/app.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`

Answer (score -1):

You need to have an additional route to serve your js file, named to the prefix/convention you're using.

```
get("/assets/js/:file") { request: Request =>
    response.ok.file(request.getParam(file))
}
```

See http://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/files/

Comment: This is a good point. See my update. But it is still unclear how to get static files conveniently.

Comment: `response.ok.file(String)` function doesn't work properly. It yields `404 Not Found`.

Comment: The definitions of the functions are `file(file: String)` and `fileOrIndex(filePath: String, indexPath: String)`. They use the param `-doc.root` as the location identifier. Remove `new File()` and just put the string in the function as it's already pointing at `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Dummy example I have in an existing project: http://pastebin.com/mqinhcyZ; `campaign.csv`, and `campaign.xls` are in `src/main/resources/*`